# hive tables store as parquet fail

Tags: hadoop, parquet

I am receiving while trying to insert data into hive table stored as parquet. I have a table with 103209 . It works when I write limit clause in select statement.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_parquet (a bigint,b int)
STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 's3n://abc/test_parquet';

insert into test_parquet select a,b from stage_mri_travel limit 100; --- works
insert into test_parquet select a,b from stage_mri_travel; --- fails


Error:
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:251)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: parquet.schema.Types$MessageTypeBuilder.addFields([Lparquet/schema/Type;)Lparquet/schema/Types$BaseGroupBuilder;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.DataWritableReadSupport.getSchemaByName(DataWritableReadSupport.java:158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.DataWritableReadSupport.init(DataWritableReadSupport.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.getSplit(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat.getRecordReader(MapredParquetInputFormat.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:66)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may exist old (i.e. 1.7.0) parquet jar. You need to make sure 1.8.0 parquet jar is present in classpath.